# nokogiri xml unescape

Tags: xml, build, nokogiri, escaping

i'm just trying out nokogiri xml builder, but am having some problem tying to unescape the content. have been spending a bit of time googgling but so far can't find the answer.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#build xml docoument
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.root{
        xml.node {
            xml.value "text1 & text2"
        }
   }
```

end
   puts builder.to_xml

output i'm get is "text1 &amp text2"

but i want it to be "text1 & text2"

Answer (score 2):

An unescaped ampersand [would not be valid XML](http://annevankesteren.nl/2004/06/ampersands-matter), hence why Nokogiri isn't letting you create that.